# Enlarge an image the way it would be used as background image

Tags: css

I have the following snippet for the image container:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="/images/xyz.jpg">
</div>

.image-container {
    width:415px;
    height:552px;
}
```

The div's size is fixed and can't be changed. Images can be different sizes. At this moment, I have the following style for the image:

```
width:100%;
height: auto;
```

This may show a lot of empty space within the container for most images because their sizes do not math the 415/552 ratio.

Now I need to make images cover the whole div space. If I make the image the background of the container, this is what I would do:

```
.image-container {
    width:415px;
    height:552px;
    background: url("/images/xyz.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

However, the images can't be background images due to a few reasons. How can I use CSS to enlarge images to achieve the same results as if they were used as background images through the above CSS. When enlarged, the image shouldn't be distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a fixed width and height on your containing div, you can use absolute positioning on the image to make it take up the full height and width, for example:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width:415px;
    height:552px;
}

.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
 }
```

**Edit**: The above css worked after some changes. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rezvj2uw/1/ for an example

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is not going to work for me. This approach would distort the image. Maybe I didn't say it clearly enough. I am hoping to achieve the same results as if the image was used as a background through `background: url("/images/xyz.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover`.

Comment: Set the object-fit to cover on the image as well and you should be good

Comment: @curious1 I've edited my answer above to include the additional property.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tested it out and this approach would make the div wider than 415px. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cj91vgpu/4/

Comment: @curious1 I've edited the initial answer now. Give it a shot. :)

Comment: It works! Initially thought this was not possible. Tried and failed. Very nice work and I have learned something. Thanks!!!

Comment: You may want to add this fiddle to your answer to let people see it
https://jsfiddle.net/rezvj2uw/1/

Comment: Added in. Not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.image-container {
    width:415px;
    height:552px;
    background-image: url("/images/xyz.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/0odgxjh3/3/

Jsfiddle second solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/0odgxjh3/9/

other solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/0odgxjh3/12/

Comment: This is not going to work because the images can't be background images.

Comment: mmm why not? did you try? the other option that you have is put an `<img />` with `position: absolute` and `z-index:-1`

Comment: if I tell you is because I already did it... no reason to be so impolite.

Comment: Sorry if my response has made you feel that way. I tried the other option, it is not working. If you have a working one, could you please create a codepen or jsfiddle to show it?

Comment: Create a codepen or jsfiddle with the issue, then I could help you

Comment: Here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/vo1swbpc/2/. I added the background to the container to show the area of div.

Comment: If it's not what you expected please try to explain the problem with other words

Comment: Could you please share with me the link to your update to the fiddle I created?

Comment: I Edited the post, here are: 
https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/0odgxjh3/3/

https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/0odgxjh3/9/

Comment: This is not what I need in two aspects. First, the image can't be made  background image. The post states this clearly. Second, the enlarged image isn't enlarged proportionally as it would be as a background image through style: `background: url("/images/xyz.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover`. Thanks for the help! Really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, a solution was selected. Appreciate your effort to help me.